# nodejs - check if fetch response is json or text

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'm new to coding and i'm using `node-fetch` and trying to check if the response is a `json` or `text` but i get an error if the response is text.

If the response is a json it will work fine but if the response is text i get an error.

The error i get:

```
invalid json response body at https://url.com/api reason: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 6
```

My code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const doFetch = async (url) => {
  try {
    let res = await fetch(url);

    try {
      return res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      return res.text();
    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('fetch error', error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You get an error coz, you have put it in the catch-block. Will you be little more clear in your question? And write the code properly. What url you are taking? and from where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check what is the content type from the header:

```
const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
```

if it's `"application/json"` then use the `json()` method. else if it's `"text/plain"`, use the `text()` method.

Comment: There are others also right? `text/plain` for text()

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help.

Comment: My pleasure my friend (:

Comment: The server's return of such a header is unwarranted.